# HTTPSサイトからHTTPのAPIへアクセス時にエラー

Tags: vue.js, webapi

以下リンク先のエラーはやはり回避不可能でしょうか？

[Mixed Contentエラー](https://ssl.sakura.ad.jp/column/mixed-content/)

開発中のWebアプリがインターネットに接続されておりhttps接続です。
そのWebサイトのフロントエンド処理からローカルネットにあるOSSのAPI(http)にアクセスしようとしています。
その際に以下のようにエラーが出ています。
[エラーメッセージ内容](https://qiita.com/yamato1491038/items/732a5fb78ec6b9be4f62)

Content Security Policyの以下を色々試しましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。
[Content Security Policyヘッダ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)

Comment: 1. 参考になりそうなQ&Aをどうぞ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content 2. ローカル開発環境をhttpsでアクセスできるようにするという無難な手もあります

Comment: ありがとうございます。１．で対応可能でした。大変さ校になりました。
２．については自己署名ですか？

Comment: 似たような話 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/92266/2376

Comment: ありがとうございます。